# how to insert a row to my db table from vb.net

Tags: vb.net

am using vb.net, and i want to insert a row to my db Table "adwPays" from my windows form.
this is my code:
        Dim CC, EngName, FreName, LanCode As String
        Dim DialCode As Integer

```
    CC = txtCC.Text
    EngName = txtEN.Text
    FreName = txtFN.Text
    LanCode = txtLC.Text
    DialCode = txtDC.Text


    Dim MyConn As New SqlConnection("Server=(local);Database=dbAjout;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim query As String
    query = "INSERT INTO adwPays (CC, Anglais,Francais,CodeLangue,IndicInter) VALUES ( ' " & CC & "','" & EngName & "','" & FreName & "','" & LanCode & "','" & DialCode & " ');"

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, MyConn)

    MyConn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    MyConn.Close()
```

BUT its giving me this error 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

any help?

Comment: i also tried cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() but its not working!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameterized query like this

```
Dim query  = "INSERT INTO adwPays (CC, Anglais,Francais,CodeLangue,IndicInter) " & 
             "VALUES (@cc, @ename, @fname, @lan, @dial)"
Using MyConn = New SqlConnection("Server=(local);Database=dbAjout;Integrated Security=True")
Using cmd = New SqlCommand(query, MyConn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cc", CC)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ename", EngName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", FreName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lan", LanCode)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dial", DialCode)
    MyConn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

Using a parameterized query allows to avoid problems with Sql Injections and clears the command text from the formatting quotes around strings and dates and also let the framework code pass the correct decimal point for the numeric types when need

I have also added a [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) around the SqlConnection and the SqlCommand to be sure that the objects are closed and destroyed. The parameters are all passed as strings, this could be wrong if any of your database fields are not of text type.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a `String` value that is longer than the database type size allows. Can you verify the type and size of each of the following fields:

- cc
- ename
- fname
- lan

Now cross-reference those sizes with what the values are in the textbox fields you are pulling them from in the UI.

My money is on one of those exceeding the database size limits.

If that is the case, then you need to introduce length checking before you attempt to save to the database.